# update and back button not working in grocerycrud codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I am using Ajax_grocery_CRUD and gc_dependent_select library in grocerry crud codeigniter but when I hit the (update and back to list) button record updated successfully but url not route to list page.

[image: screenshoot for my issue]

Comment: As seen from your screenshot some sort of error is generated in Javascript file(Javascript is breaking due to `<`).So try to solve that error first.

Answer (score 0):

Well my friend, it seems that at server side, the system is generating some notice / warning which is pushed along with the output for the request. If you can fix the same .. great - fix it and the issue will be solved. If there are trouble fixing the warning / notices - will recommend you look in setting up the app mode from development to production and such notices / warnings will disappear. There onwards you should be able to get in proper desired results.